# Serial communication behavior

Tags: linux, serial-port, driver, hardware, communication

Im trying to learn about serial communication and I saw that command in below link

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-HOWTO-19.html#pinout_

Only 3 of the 9 pins have a fixed assignment: transmit, receive and signal ground. This is fixed by the hardware and you can't change it.

***But the other signal lines are controlled by software and may do (and mean) almost anything at all.***

So, these 6 pins, are they reliable to control state of them?

I have many devices, is there any way to make hardware handshaking in a common way?

what I have to do, If some drivers does not handle this pins accurately?

Is there any way to make them fixed assigned by program?

Comment: 3 wire communication is quite normal. It all depends on what device you are talking to and if the hardware handshaking signals are required. This might help http://www.windmill.co.uk/handshaking.html

Comment: So, what I understand, I cannot use a common interface for all device if I use hardware handshaking, right?

Comment: with serial communication there is nothing common across all devices, BUT 3 wire communication using XON/XOFF is probably the most widely used.

Comment: *"But the other signal lines are controlled by software"* -- Not necessarily true.    FWIW I don't agree with that source you cite; it's not accurate.  There is no rigid standard for RS232 connectors.  There are only conventions.  Since the advent of the IBM PC, that has become the most widely followed wiring convention.  IOW you're reading a document, and not realizing the assumptions it makes and its specific scope.

Comment: Your question is off topic.  Signal assignment to pins of a serial port connector is a pure hardware topic.